# Fusionar etiquetas "node", "nodejs" y "node.js"

Tags: soporte, estado-completado, etiquetas, sinónimos-de-etiquetas

Estaba mirando la etiqueta [node](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/node), y al parecer no hay ninguna diferencia con las etiquetas [nodejs](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nodejs) o [node.js](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/node.js).

Propongo fusionar o poner como sinónimos las tres etiquetas. De preferencia, poner como *maestro* la que tenga más preguntas, en este caso [nodejs](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nodejs).

Si usted es experto en nodejs, acceda a este enlace para votar.

https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/nodejs/synonyms

También, un tema separado es que, el nombre de la etiqueta [node](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/node) me suena a *nodo (lista enlazada)*, no sé si deba crearse una etiqueta exclusiva para el manejo de nodos.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo con que se cree el sinónimo. Lo único, el sistema de votación efectivamente son las publicaciones en meta. En meta **siempre** se vota por la propuesta en sí, especialmente con las preguntas de [característica-nueva]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La propuesta prospero y ahora las etiquetas [node](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/node) y [node.js](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/node.js) son sinonimos de [nodejs](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nodejs)

https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/nodejs/synonyms

Comment: ¡Bien! No me lo esperaba. Además vi la descripción que puso @aldanux, estuvo bien que la hayas aprobado, quedó bueno.

Comment: Efectivamente aprobé los sinónimos tras la aceptación de la propuesta y realicé la fusión. Ya no existen en el sistema las primeras dos etiquetas :). Un saludo y gracias!